# Issue with Generalized Dice Loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, niftynet

I was adapting the generalized dice loss provided by niftynet to use on my own tensorflow network which produces a probability for a single label. In order to use the generalized dice loss, I added this line to the beginning of the file (I am working with 2D data):

`prediction = tf.concat([1 - prediction, prediction], axis=3)`

I am using a batch size of 1. When I tested type_weight for Square, Simple, and Uniform, I am getting very similar results. It seems that ref_vol should be summed, or am I missing this?